PsyPlay theme problems
I have two problems with the WP psyplay theme and I need someone to help me find a solution.
The first problem has to do with the fact that the structure of some links in the theme should be:
mysite/episode/name-of-the-series-season#-episode#
but instead the links appear as follows
mysite/episode/name-of-the-series-season#-episode#-season#-episode#
What should I do to make the links appear correctly and direct users to the episodes of each series?
The second problem is that the thumbnails of the movies and series appear perfectly in home, but when I go to the Top IMDb page, or Trending or any other page, the thumbnails do not appear. How can I make the thumbnails appear on all pages?
I know there are hundreds of people here for whom this question is "child's play" and I would appreciate if someone could help me to solve this couple of problems.
Thanks in advance.
I've been looking at the theme code but can't find where to fix what's wrong. I am not an experienced programmer and that is why I have not been able to work out the bugs in the theme.
